# Excel auto copy

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have problem in ecxel where when I input a data in one cell which is A1 that data should be copy in another sheet(sheet) when I hit enter in the keyboard, and when I input data again on that cell which is A1 that should be copy on that another sheet(sheet2) again but in the next row when I hit enter. Im not good in coding.

I try basic formulas in excel searchinh in youtube for tutorials. None of that can solve my problem

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. Please note that this is not a free code writing service. What you have described is not a problem, but the goal you wish to achieve. FWIW, you need VBA to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

### A Worksheet Change: Copy Each Entered Value to a Column

- The following screenshot illustrates what has happened in `Sheet2` after entering `1,2,3,4 and 5` into cell `A1` of `Sheet1`.

[image]

- Copy the following code into the sheet module of the source worksheet (`Sheet1`), the one where you will be entering the values.
  (In the *Project Explorer*, double-click on `Sheet1(Sheet1)`, and the correct window will open.)
- Observe the blue-ish title bar where it shows `... Sheet1 (Code)`: note that this `Sheet1` refers to the `Sheet1` on the left (in the *Project Explorer*) that is not in parentheses. It is the sheet's code name. The name in parentheses is the tab name (the one you see in Excel) and it could be different.

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    ' Reference the source cell.
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Me.Range(SRC_CELL)
    ' Check if the source cell was not changed.
    If Intersect(sCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    Dim dCell As Range:
    Set dCell = Me.Parent.Sheets(DST_SHEET).Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    With dCell
        ' Reference the destination range, the range starting from
        ' the first destination cell to the last cell in the column
        ' i.e. e.g. for 'A2' this means the range 'A2:A1048576'.
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        ' Attempt to reference the last (bottom-most) non-empty cell
        ' of the destination range.
        Dim dlCell As Range:
        Set dlCell = drg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        ' If the attempt was succesful i.e. there is a non-empty cell,...
        If Not dlCell Is Nothing Then
            ' ... check if the last cell is not the last cell
            ' of the destination range (there is no cell below it).
            If dlCell.Row = Me.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub
            ' Reference the cell below the last cell.
            Set dCell = dlCell.Offset(1)
        'Else ' If the attempt failed i.e. all cells are empty,...
            ' ... do nothing i.e. use the already referenced destination cell.
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Write the value from the source cell to the destination cell.
    dCell.Value = sCell.Value
    
End Sub
```