# How to truncate numbers rather than rounding in cells where a formula being applied?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to calculate mean and standard deviation of an entered values in a table. But I need the final values to be truncated rather than rounded.[Microsoft 365 for Mac]

I need Excel to show 4 decimal places without rounding them. For example, for 3.88888, I need 3.8888 rather than 3.8889.

For example, I have `IFERROR(AVERAGE(A1:A10),"")` in cell `A11`. How can I truncate the average value?

Does anyone know how to do that with VBA?

Thanks

Need to implement VBA to truncate the intermediate calculated data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TRUNC` with your existing formula:

```
=IFERROR(TRUNC(AVERAGE(A1:A10),4),"")
```